# How to serialize a classes that included at System.Net.IPAddress property?

Tags: c#

I want to serialize my class having property IPAddress.

```
public class Person
{
    public IPAddress MasterIP { get; set; }
    public Person(){}
}


public void SerializeMyClass()
{
    Person obj=new Person();
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(obj);
}
```

But I am getting error:

> "can not serialize IPaddress because it has no empty constructor"

Comment: Pretty important to understand why this restriction exists.  .NET is trying to wean you off the representation of an IP address.  IPv6 is very important to solve the address space problem, it will come to your neighborhood some day soon.  If you want to serialize then you have to choose a representation, like Int64.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question instead of changing this one. You got an answer based on why `IPAddress` isn't serializable, which with your edit became invalid. If you want to know how to serialize a Dictionary<IPAddress, string>, either search for that on the Internet or, if you can't find it there, ask a **new** question. Based on this, I'm rolling back your question to rev.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't - XmlSerializer can only serialize public properties/fields of public classes that have public parameterless constructors. You can either look into other serializer type (like BinaryFormatter) or hack your class like:

```
public class Person {
  [XmlIgnore]
  public IPAddress MasterIP { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("MasterIP")]
  public string MasterIPForXml {
    get { return MasterIP.ToString(); }
    set { MasterIP = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null :
      IPAddress.Parse(value); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the MaterIPForXML element need to be public?

Comment: @GeorgW. - yes it does. XmlSerializer is ignoring non-public properties.