# Instantiating XAML Object with non-primitive property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What do I have to code to initialize a object with a non-primitive property.

Like when having the following Model and ViewModel:

```
public class ListEntry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListEntry> ListEntries { get; set; }
}
```

then I can code this XAML DesignData:

```
<nc:ViewModel
    xmlns:nc="clr-namespace:NetWorkItOut.NetworkClasses">
    <nc:ViewModel.ListEntries>
        <nc:ListEntry ID="1" IP="192.168.178.1" />
        <nc:ListEntry ID="2" IP="192.168.178.255" />
    </nc:ViewModel.ListEntries>
</nc:ViewModel>
```

and everything works. But when replacing

```
public string IP { get; set; }
```

with

```
public IPAddress IP { get; set; }
```

this does not work (since IPaddress has no constructor that takes a string.

So how can I solve this? (Displaying the IP Value with the design data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize a classes that included at System.Net.IPAddress property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139723/how-to-serialize-a-classes-that-included-at-system-net-ipaddress-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to wrap the `IPAddress` with an additional `string` property:

```
public IPAddress IP { get; set; }
public string StringIP
{
    get
    {
        return IP.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        IP = IPAddress.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the wrapped property to set the IP:

```
<nc:ListEntry ID="2" StringIP="192.168.178.255" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `TypeConverter` that converts from `string` to `IPAddress`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
...

public class IPAddressConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return IPAddress.Parse((string)value);
    }
}
```

Register the `TypeConverter` for the `IP` property like this:

```
public class ListEntry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(IPAddressConverter))]
    public IPAddress IP { get; set; }
}
```